# Run-Time Error 430 for Power point application in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create powerpoint presentation through VBA Code and I selected library (early binding) reference in tools also. But I'm unable to create Powerpoint application through VBA. I wrote the below code and i'm getting the error as **"Class does not support automation or does not support expected interface"**. Could you please help to resolve the issue.

```
Sub CreatePPT()

Dim MYPPT As PowerPoint.Application
Set MYPPT = New PowerPoint.Application

With MYPPT

    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Activate

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: where to change, I changed in both places. But still getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a Presentation :

```
Sub CreatePPT()

Dim MYPPT As PowerPoint.Application
Set MYPPT = New PowerPoint.Application

Dim PPTPresent as PowerPoint.Presentation

With MYPPT

    .Visible = msoTrue
     set PPTPresent = .Presentations.add
End With

End Sub
```